# how to make a method for drawing a large number of shapes

Tags: java, graphics

I have a program that draws with simple shapes, but I don't understand how to combine some shapes into methods to make the code smaller

```
private void DrawEventPerformed(DrawEventArg evt) {
        Graphics gr = evt.getGraphics();

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#CD853F")));
        gr.fillOval(300, 100, 200, 180);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#F4A460")));
        gr.fillOval(340, 180, 120, 80);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#000000")));
        gr.fillPolygon(new int[] {380, 400, 420}, new int[] {200, 230, 200}, 3);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#000000")));
        gr.fillOval(340, 180, 20, 30);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#000000")));
        gr.fillOval(440, 180, 20, 30);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#CD853F")));
        gr.fillOval(290, 80, 80, 80);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#CD853F")));
        gr.fillOval(273, 260, 250, 290);

        gr.setColor(Color.getColor("", Color.decode("#F4A460")));
        gr.fillOval(323, 350, 150, 180);
    }
```

Comment: Use an array or ArrayList of values, draw the shapes using a `for` loop, reading values out of the array.

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. There are many ways to break down a method into smaller pieces.